# A feature distribution is nearly normal: what does that imply for my ML model?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

The statement of my exercise says : `distribution of feature_3 is a hint of how the data is generated`. I try to understand what I should infer from that for the rest of my ETL or ML model..

I have plotted the Q-Q plot of this feature. The distribution seems fairly normal. What can I infer from this information for the rest of my ETL or ML model ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of machine learning models assume an underlying data distribution for them to function well.

So, coming back to your question, there are some `ML` techniques that assume that the data fed into them are normally (or Gaussian) distributed. These are `Gaussian naive Bayes`, `Least Squares based (regression)` models, `LDA`, `QDA`. So the statement you are referring to implies that your data was generated using such an algorithm and are normally distributed. See, [here](https://tekmarathon.com/2015/11/13/importance-of-data-distribution-in-training-machine-learning-models/) for a brief visual explanation of this and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/can-anyone-tell-me-why-we-always-use-the-gaussian-distribution-in-machine-learni) for an explanation on the importance of normal distribution in `Machine Learning`.

In addition, please note that there are other algorithms (e.g. `SVM`s, `Random Forests` used for `regression`/`classification`, `Decision trees`, `Gradient Boosted Trees` etc) that do not assume any type of underlying data distribution.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. I am using `Logistic Regression` further in my work. From what I understand from your post + links, this algorithm does require the normality of the distribution, right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The use of it implies that the data is normally distributed.